# Can I build a fully open source app with .Net Core

Tags: c#, open-source, .net-core

I am thinking about starting an open source project and right now I am deciding what technology stack to use.

At the moment, my main coding experience is using C# and I am wondering if I can build a truly open source application using .Net Core?

I appreciate that this might sound like the answers to this question might be quite opinion-based, so I will be more than happy to correct it and add more details if needed.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what 'Open source' means. Open source simply means that whatever you build, you make it public to the world, so everyone can read how you've done various things in your project. It is code- and technology-agnostic. As such, the obvious answer to your question is yes, but you're likely asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Falgantil: Open source does not just mean giving read access to your sources, but also giving the right to make changes to it (under certain conditions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an application is open-source or not depends on all the copyright licenses that apply to the different parts of the application. Your code must be published under an open-source license and all third-party code that you use must have a compatible license.

The .Net Core framework is licensed under the MIT license, which is a permissive open-source license. This makes it very much possible to build open-source applications using the .Net Core framework.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if I can build a trully open source application using .Net Core?

Yes you can if you chose to. [.Net Core is open source itself, covered by the MIT licence](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/LICENSE.TXT) and you are free to use it for any purpose (subject to the terms of the MIT licence), including open source projects of your own.